cmake with ninja and custom command corrupts rsp file
cmake does not build due to corrupted .rsp file (cmake 3.27.6 with ninja 1.10.2 on Windows).
The exectuable in the project has a few modules:
add_executable( ${target}
 ...
 $<TARGET_OBJECTS:AdcIn_MODULE>
 #$<TARGET_OBJECTS:Can_MODULE>
 $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Cmp_MODULE>
 ...
)

Before linking, I call a windows script (parse_obj.cmd) parsing the object files:
foreach(obj ${MY_OBJ_LIST})
 add_custom_command(
  TARGET ${target}
  PRE_LINK
  COMMAND cmd /c parse_obj.cmd "$<PATH:CMAKE_PATH,NORMALIZE,$<TARGET_OBJECTS:${obj}>>"
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${MY_CMD_PATH}
  VERBATIM
 )
endforeach()

Everything was fine:
[build] [27/27 100% :: 6.884] Linking C executable CCSProject.out.exe
[build] <Linking>
[build] Translating to Intel format...
[build]    "CCSProject.out" codestart ==> codestart
[build]    "CCSProject.out" .TI.ramfunc ==> .TI.ramfunc
[build]    "CCSProject.out" Cla1Prog ==> Cla1Prog
[build]    "CCSProject.out" .text ==> .text
[build]    "CCSProject.out" .const ==> .const
[build]    "CCSProject.out" .cinit ==> .cinit
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:07.157
[build] Build finished with exit code 0

until I added the $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Can_MODULE> module to the target:
[build] [27/27 100% :: 5.336] Linking C executable CCSProject.out.exe
[build] FAILED: CCSProject.out.exe 
[build] cmd.exe /C "cmd.exe /C "cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/01_BSW/AdcIn/CMakeFiles/AdcIn_MODULE.dir/AdcIn_CpuAdcConversion.c.obj;W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/01_BSW/AdcIn/CMakeFiles/AdcIn_MODULE.dir/AdcIn_Temperature.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/01_BSW/Can/CMakeFiles/Can_MODULE.dir/CanCmd.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/01_BSW/Cmp/CMakeFiles/Cmp_MODULE.dir/Cmp.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/01_BSW/Dio/CMakeFiles/Dio_MODULE.dir/DioCmd.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/01_BSW/Nvm/CMakeFiles/Nvm_MODULE.dir/Nvm.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/01_BSW/Pwm/CMakeFiles/Pwm_MODULE.dir/Pwm.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/01_BSW/Wdg/CMakeFiles/Wdg_MODULE.dir/Wdg.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/01_BSW/Sched/CMakeFiles/Sched_MODULE.dir/Sched.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/01_BSW/SciCmd/CMakeFiles/SciCmd_MODULE.dir/SciCmd.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/02_CDD/Cla/CMakeFiles/Cla_MODULE.dir/Cla_TaskIsr.cla.obj;W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/02_CDD/Cla/CMakeFiles/Cla_MODULE.dir/Cla_Cfg.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/02_CDD/FwdCtrl/CMakeFiles/FwdCtrl_MODULE.dir/FwdCtrl.cla.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/02_CDD/RvsCtrl/CMakeFiles/RvsCtrl_MODULE.dir/RvsCtrl.cla.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/03_RTE/Main/CMakeFiles/Main_MODULE.dir/Main.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/04_ASW/Derate/CMakeFiles/Derate_MODULE.dir/Derate.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/04_ASW/Fault/CMakeFiles/Fault_MODULE.dir/Fault.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/04_ASW/State/CMakeFiles/State_MODULE.dir/State.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/05_DBG/RealTimeBuff/CMakeFiles/RealTimeBuff_MODULE.dir/RealTimeBuff.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/05_DBG/VScope/CMakeFiles/VScope_MODULE.dir/VScope.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/device/CMakeFiles/device_MODULE.dir/f28004x_codestartbranch.asm.obj;W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject/device/CMakeFiles/device_MODULE.dir/device.c.obj && cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\utils\cmd && cmd /c parse_obj.cmd W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/MCAL/CMakeFiles/MCAL_MODULE.dir/c2000ware_libraries.c.obj;W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/MCAL/CMakeFiles/MCAL_MODULE.dir/board.c.obj;W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/MCAL/CMakeFiles/MCAL_MODULE.dir/clb_config.c.obj && cd W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\build" && C:\ti\ccs1260\ccs\tools\compiler\ti-cgt-c2000_22.6.1.LTS\bin\cl2000.exe  -v28  -ml  -mt  --cla_support=cla2  --float_support=fpu32  --tmu_support=tmu0  --vcu_support=vcu0  --advice:performance=all  -Ooff  --define=_FLASH  --define=CPU1  --diag_suppress=10063  --diag_warning=225  --diag_wrap=off  --display_error_number  --abi=eabi  --cla_background_task=on  -z  --stack_size=0x100  --warn_sections  --reread_libs  --diag_wrap=off  --display_error_number  --xml_link_info=empty_sysconfig_100pz_linkInfo.xml  --entry_point=code_start  --rom_model -mW:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build/CCSProject.map W:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/CCSProject/28004x_flash_lnk.cmd -o "CCSProject.out"  CMakeFiles\CCSProject.out.rsp  && cmd.exe /C "cd /D W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\build && C:\ti\ccs1260\ccs\tools\compiler\ti-cgt-c2000_22.6.1.LTS\bin\hex2000.exe --romwidth=16 --diag_wrap=off --intel -o CCSProject.hex CCSProject.out""
[build] <Linking>
[build] "CMakeFiles\CCSProject.out.rsp", line 26: error #10008-D: cannot find file "W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\c2000ware"
[build] "CMakeFiles\CCSProject.out.rsp", line 26: error #10008-D: cannot find file "C:\ti\ccs1260\ccs\tools\compiler\ti"
[build] fatal error #10296: cannot open output file "re-sdk\driverlib\f28004x\driverlib\ccs\Debug\driverlib.lib" for writing
[build] 
[build] >> Compilation failure
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[proc] The command: W:\Technology\Tools\cmake\bin\cmake.EXE --build w:/GIT/4xLLC_FW/build --config Debug --target all -j 8 -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:10.035
[rollbar] Unhandled exception: Unhandled Promise rejection: build Error: No index file found. {}

However, if I comment the COMMAND cmd /c parse_obj.cmd ..., it builds again:
[build] [27/27 100% :: 3.940] Linking C executable CCSProject.out.exe
[build] <Linking>
[build] Translating to Intel format...
[build]    "CCSProject.out" codestart ==> codestart
[build]    "CCSProject.out" .TI.ramfunc ==> .TI.ramfunc
[build]    "CCSProject.out" Cla1Prog ==> Cla1Prog
[build]    "CCSProject.out" .text ==> .text
[build]    "CCSProject.out" .const ==> .const
[build]    "CCSProject.out" .cinit ==> .cinit
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:04.186
[build] Build finished with exit code 0

The .rsp looks like the following
CCSProject\03_RTE\Main\CMakeFiles\Main_MODULE.dir\Main.c.obj
CCSProject\device\CMakeFiles\device_MODULE.dir\f28004x_codestartbranch.asm.obj
CCSProject\device\CMakeFiles\device_MODULE.dir\device.c.obj
MCAL\CMakeFiles\MCAL_MODULE.dir\c2000ware_libraries.c.obj
MCAL\CMakeFiles\MCAL_MODULE.dir\board.c.obj
MCAL\CMakeFiles\MCAL_MODULE.dir\clb_config.c.obj
CCSProject\01_BSW\AdcIn\CMakeFiles\AdcIn_MODULE.dir\AdcIn_CpuAdcConversion.c.obj
CCSProject\01_BSW\AdcIn\CMakeFiles\AdcIn_MODULE.dir\AdcIn_Temperature.c.obj
CCSProject\01_BSW\Can\CMakeFiles\Can_MODULE.dir\CanCmd.c.obj
CCSProject\01_BSW\Cmp\CMakeFiles\Cmp_MODULE.dir\Cmp.c.obj
CCSProject\01_BSW\Dio\CMakeFiles\Dio_MODULE.dir\DioCmd.c.obj
CCSProject\01_BSW\Nvm\CMakeFiles\Nvm_MODULE.dir\Nvm.c.obj
CCSProject\01_BSW\Pwm\CMakeFiles\Pwm_MODULE.dir\Pwm.c.obj
CCSProject\01_BSW\Sched\CMakeFiles\Sched_MODULE.dir\Sched.c.obj
CCSProject\01_BSW\SciCmd\CMakeFiles\SciCmd_MODULE.dir\SciCmd.c.obj
CCSProject\01_BSW\Wdg\CMakeFiles\Wdg_MODULE.dir\Wdg.c.obj
CCSProject\02_CDD\Cla\CMakeFiles\Cla_MODULE.dir\Cla_TaskIsr.cla.obj
CCSProject\02_CDD\Cla\CMakeFiles\Cla_MODULE.dir\Cla_Cfg.c.obj
CCSProject\02_CDD\Cpu\CMakeFiles\Cpu_MODULE.dir\Cpu_TaskIsr.c.obj
CCSProject\02_CDD\FwdCtrl\CMakeFiles\FwdCtrl_MODULE.dir\FwdCtrl.cla.obj
CCSProject\02_CDD\RvsCtrl\CMakeFiles\RvsCtrl_MODULE.dir\RvsCtrl.cla.obj
CCSProject\04_ASW\Derate\CMakeFiles\Derate_MODULE.dir\Derate.c.obj
CCSProject\04_ASW\Fault\CMakeFiles\Fault_MODULE.dir\Fault.c.obj
CCSProject\04_ASW\State\CMakeFiles\State_MODULE.dir\State.c.obj
CCSProject\05_DBG\RealTimeBuff\CMakeFiles\RealTimeBuff_MODULE.dir\RealTimeBuff.c.obj
CCSProject\05_DBG\VScope\CMakeFiles\VScope_MODULE.dir\VScope.c.obj  W:\GIT\4xLLC_FW\c2000ware-core-sdk\driverlib\f28004x\driverlib\ccs\Debug\driverlib.lib  C:\ti\ccs1260\ccs\tools\compiler\ti-cgt-c2000_22.6.1.LTS\lib\libc.a

At the end of the file, there are no new lines between the last three objects/libraries.
Is it normal?
When it builds ok, I added the -d keeprsp flag to ninja, but the .rsp is still missing, so I have no working reference.
Thanks in advance for your help
